# mac Books.app copy text from a epub book, the content is truncated as ellipsis

Tags: macos, mac, copy-paste, books

when I copy text from books, seems there is size limitation, the copy is truncated, please see an example:

“on this earth I’m going to live. Why be only half alive? Every minute a person spends worrying about dying is just one minute that fellow might as well have been dead.”
I had to leave at that point, because I had to be on a certain plane for Detroit. On the plane the second but much more pleasant experience occurred. After the noise of the takeoff, I heard a ticking sound. Rather startled, I glanced at the fellow sitting beside me, for the sound seemed to be coming from him.
He smiled a big smile and said, “Oh, it’s not a bomb. It’s just my heart.”
I was obviously surprised, so he proceeded to tell me what had happened.
Just twenty-one days before, he had undergone an operation that involved putting a plastic valve into his heart. The ticking sound, he explained, would continue for several months, until new tissue had grown over the artificial valve. I asked him what he was going to do.
“Oh,” he said, “I’ve got big plans. I’m going to study law when I get back to Minnesota. Someday I hope to be in government work. The doctors tell me I must[…]”

Excerpt From
...
This material may be protected by copyright.

Please see this: The doctors tell me I must[…]”,  it was truncated as [...].
Very weird thing is, when I google, no one reported this thing.

Comment: What kind of book are you copying from & from/to what app? file type - pdf, txt… etc. That's certainly nowhere near enough text to choke the copy buffer - in fact I've never known it choke. I can copypaste entire chapters from epub books [chapters are an obstacle to copying the entire book, but that's a file limitation, not copy buffer].

Comment: I assume you mean the Apple supplied Books.app? You could try Calibre, I use it to get non Amazon stuff onto my Kindle. It allows editing, converting and reading all kinds of ebooks. Apple might be locking down books.app but Calibre won't.

Comment: yes, I am talking about Books.app, epub file format

Comment: Calibre I don't think can read books from Books.app so you should get your books another way

Comment: this seems to be a restriction for books in ePub format when copied within Apple Books - even when the book isn’t copyrighted (any longer).

Comment: It's a DRM issue. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422937/how-to-copy-text-from-a-book-in-an-application-without-a-quote-and-instructions for a similar question and its answer.

Comment: I am not talking about Excerpt from, I am talking the content before Excerpt from, it was truncated, I can manually remove all those Excerpt from